# objective-c ios app layout

Tags: objective-c, iphone, layout

How to fit size for `iphone 5s`, `iphone 6s` and `iphone 6plus`.

Do I need to make **separate** story board if so could you any body tell me how to make **separate** story board for a specific **view controller**.

Comment: please tag which language you use like `objective-c ` or `swift` @Manzoor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not use a separate storyboard for each screen size.  The system contains functionality specifically so you do not have to do that.

Apple provides lots of really great documentation on this topic online.  I would recommend that you start with this site:

https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

In particular you want to look up information about Auto Layout and `NSLayoutConstraint`.  There are several WWDC videos (linked from the page above) that discuss the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoLayout then there is no need for separate storyboards for each device. AutoLayout managed all things for you if you provide proper constraints and size classes.

If you really need a separate storyboards for each device so here is the solution:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UIViewController *initialViewController = nil;
UIStoryboard *storyboard;
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height ==  667)
    {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"6board" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    }else if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 736){
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"6plus" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    }else{
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
}else{
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ipadboard" bundle:nil];
    initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
}
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
```

[image: StoryBoards for diffrent devices]

Hope it's helped you... Happy Codding

Comment: How to add auto layout programmatically?